# #1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

Tags: sql

Ao migrar a base de dados da MAMP para o servidor 
esta me a dar este erro?
Pode me ajudar?

Erro
Comando SQL:

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
```

Mensagem do MySQL:

> `#1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'`

Comment: A versão do servidores MySQL é a mesma?

Comment: não sei como posso verificar?

Comment: eu esta no MAC a desenvolver o site.

Comment: e agora ia fazer a migração para o meu alojamento.

Comment: Faz um `select @@version` nos dois servidores.

Comment: DEsculpa, mas não ei onde faço isso?

Comment: No alojamento a versão é esta

Comment: Apache
MySQL client version: 5.1.73
PHP extension: mysql

Comment: e no mamp é 5.6.33

Comment: Parece que vc usou um charset que não é suportado por uma versão antiga(5.1.x).

Comment: `select @@version` vc roda no phpmyadmin ou no workbench para descobrir a versão MySQL (causa do problema).

Comment: Sim no phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com o manual:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

O charset `utf8mb4` foi introduzido na versão 5.5.3. Sendo assim, realmente a versão remota não tem como aceitar este dump se for menor que isto.

Como disse o [@rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91) nos comentários, você pode verificar a versão com a *query* a seguir:

```
SELECT @@version
```

Uma solução, caso não possa atualizar o servidor remoto, seria você usar o *charset* `utf8` mesmo. A única restrição é que caracteres Unicode com código acima de 65535 não seriam armazenados, mas isto provavelmente não será um grande problema a não ser que você precise de suporte a línguas mais remotamente usadas ou símbolos muito fora do cotidiano.